# How to generate a non-animated GIF image client-side with JS?

Tags: javascript, image, gif

Say I have a 20x20 two-dimensional array of boolean values in JS.

Where the boolean is true, I'd like to generate a black pixel. Where the boolean is false, I'd like to generate a transparent pixel. Then after the processing is done, I can download the image.

Either it'd be a case of generating the image in a HTML document which I can then right click -> Save As, or something I can paste into my browser's URL bar starting with `data:image/gif`

I'm only using GIF because I need the transparency - a PNG would work just as well however I gather that PNG is unnecessarily difficult.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: look into canvas API and img tag data URI

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean

Comment: google those terms and you'll see what I mean